# How to convert a MKV video to a less CPU intensive video format?

Tags: windows, video, conversion, matroska

I have a couple of videos at 1920x800 that use the MKV format (4.7 GB).  A friend of mine has an old PC that has some problems playing them; the CPU is working at nearly 100%.

Is it possible to convert these videos to a less CPU intensive video format? The final size is not a problem, it can also double or more.

Into which format should I convert it and which software for Windows should I use (better if free)?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: See: http://superuser.com/questions/31876/convert-mkv-h264-video-so-it-can-be-played-on-a-mid-range-sony-ericsson-phone

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MKV is only the container, so that's not the problem. It is a question of the codec or the picture size. Processing large image sizes needs much more power than small images. So I think the problem here is rather the image size. Maybe you should try to resample it to 720p or even 576p.

Comment: @Martin
Thank you, it is clear now. I saw the Video use CABAC, maybe I should try without CABAC active, I read on wiki that it could be lighter to elaborate